# PHP - need the data from rates.rate based on the value of MAX(date_start)

Tags: php, max

Being a bit dim this morning have this query

```
$result = $DBH->query("SELECT MAX(date_start) as date_start, rates.rate as rate FROM rates WHERE unitID=$ID AND rates.date_start <= $start ");
```

which only half works by that I mean I always get the max date but `rates.rate` does not update, to explain more, I need the data from `rates.rate` based on the value of `MAX(date_start)`

Sorry if not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date_start,
       rate
FROM   rates
WHERE  unitid = ?
       AND date_start <= ?
ORDER  BY date_start DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: Sorry xdazz need to use 'Max()' as there could be a number of date_starts that are less than '$start'for each '$ID'

Comment: @WatkinParrot `ORDER  BY date_start DESC LIMIT 1` gives you the max, just try it.

Comment: OOPs see said being dim this morning ;)